# SlideAnimation Not Starting Again After Calling SetState()

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a simple class for animating a widget into the screen:

```
class CustomSlideAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String FROM_LEFT = 'FROM_LEFT';
  static const String FROM_RIGHT = 'FROM_RIGHT';
  final String from;
  final Widget child;

  const CustomSlideAnimation(
      {Key key, this.from = FROM_LEFT, @required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSlideAnimationState createState() => _CustomSlideAnimationState();
}

class _CustomSlideAnimationState extends State<CustomSlideAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    _offsetAnimation = widget.from == CustomSlideAnimation.FROM_LEFT
        ? Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            parent: _animationController,
          ))
        : Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            curve: Curves.linear,
            parent: _animationController,
          ));
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _offsetAnimation,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

And a simple app to demonstrate the problem:

```
void main() => runApp(Test());

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool widget1 = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: widget1
              ? CustomSlideAnimation(
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text('widget1'),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        widget1 = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  from: CustomSlideAnimation.FROM_LEFT,
                )
              : CustomSlideAnimation(
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text('widget2'),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        widget1 = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  from: CustomSlideAnimation.FROM_LEFT,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I start the app for first time the **Text** widget as expected slides in to the screen,
but then I tap it and thus calling setState() the second **Text** widget just appears suddenly into the screen and no slide transition happens.

I printed the times when build get called in all the classes and I see that setState() is triggering builds in **Test** and **CustomSlideTransition** classes but not triggering **initState()** in the **CustomSlideTransition**.

EDIT for more clarification: even putting `controller.forward()` inside the `build()` method didn't work.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `UniqueKey()` to every `CustomSlideAnimation()` to tell flutter to treat them like different widgets.

```
void main() => runApp(Test());

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool widget1 = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: widget1
              ? CustomSlideAnimation(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text('widget1'),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        widget1 = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  from: CustomSlideAnimation.FROM_LEFT,
                )
              : CustomSlideAnimation(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Text('widget2'),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        widget1 = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  from: CustomSlideAnimation.FROM_LEFT,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, keep `controller.forward()` inside `initState()`

Comment: Now I saw your answer after I refresh my browser, can you tell me if the workaround is good solution?

Comment: You shouldn't put `controller.forward` inside your `build()` method. `Build()` can be called up to 60 times per second, you should keep it out of there. It may cause performance issues

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the reason is in the keys and widget trees as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc) video.
When the setState was called without **CustomSlideTransition** having a unique  key, then the framework did not recreate the **State** object of this class again and it instead used the **State** object of the previous widget which had the `AnimationStatus` as completed

But now with keys each time the framework creates a new State object and calls `initState()` where the controller is reset and the animation starts normally.

I also found a workaround but I don't know if it is as efficient as the "keys" solution:

Without adding a key to the **CustomSlideTransition** widget,I can, in the `build()` method of this widget, do these two commands:

```
_animationController.reset();
_animationController.forward();
```

and remove the call to `_animationController.forward();` in `initState()`.